# Git-ftp add sharp symbol (#) to folders & files names in the root dir of repo

Tags: git, ftp, git-ftp

I use [Git-ftp](https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp) scripts to uploading of my project via FTP on shared hosting.
But there is a problem - during uploading git-ftp add sharp (#) symbol to folders & files names in the root dir of repository:
[[image]]

What is the reason of such behaviour of Git-ftp? Or may be there are some other reasons?

I use win7x64 OS. MINGV32 (git for windows)

Comment: Daniel, thank you for editing. I'm  new here/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem solution is here: https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp/issues/269
(reason is a bug in MINGV)
Solution: update Git for windows: https://git-scm.com/download/win