# Why does git-ftp don't overwrite files on ftp server?

Tags: git, git-ftp

Mates,
Im trying to push some files on my ftp server using git-ftp, but when i try:

```
git ftp push
```

the uploaded files appears on my ftp with a "#" (example: the app dir is uploaded as #app) and don't overwrite my modified files.

How could i solve that?

PS: Im using windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

) 
You should update your `Git for Windows` - I've solved same problem by updating it, [look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38170786/git-ftp-add-sharp-symbol-to-folders-files-names-in-the-root-dir-of-repo)